# Pivot point within N bars after lowest/highest point

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Could anyone please help me by giving an example on finding the nearer Pivot Low point after lowest point was found?

I'm currently able to find the lowest point, but had no idea how to find the nearer pivot after the lowest.

```
lowest = ta.lowest(100)
highest = ta.highest(100)
//I would like to find the next pivot point after the lowest point was found
```

I had found the way of writing the scripts and the results sample as below.

```
//Nearer Pivot Point Searching var pivotLowArray = array.new_float(10) var pivotLowBarIndexArray = array.new_float(10)

//Pivot Point Calculation Start pl = ta.pivotlow(pivotLeft, pivotRight) tf = 100

if not na(pl)
    array.unshift(pivotLowArray, pl)
    array.unshift(pivotLowBarIndexArray, bar_index - pivotRight)

findNearerPivotPoint(sl) =>
    int indexL = 0
    int index  = 0
    float priceL = 0.
    int sizeL = 0
    pLArray = array.new_float(1)
    if array.size(pivotLowBarIndexArray) > 0
        while bar_index - array.get(pivotLowBarIndexArray, indexL) <= tf and indexL <= array.size(pivotLowBarIndexArray)
            array.push(pLArray, array.get(pivotLowArray, indexL))
            indexL += 1

    array.sort(pLArray, order.ascending)
    sizeL := array.size(pLArray)         
    if array.size(pLArray) > 1
        if sl > array.get(pLArray, sizeL - 2)
            priceL := sl
        else
            while index < array.size(pLArray)
                priceL := array.get(pLArray, index)
                if index >= array.size(pLArray) or sl < priceL
                    break
                index += 1
        priceL
    else
        priceL := sl
    [priceL]
     [nearerLowest] = findNearerPivotPoint(lowest)
```

Comment: You should post a snippet of your code, not only a partial code for getting help. Anyway, what you posted is not a pivot but the highest and lowest value of the first 100 bars. You need the correct formula to calculate Pivots Point. Here there's an article: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pivotpoint.asp